# Shortcode within Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So, I have a following ajax setup:

**PHP: menu.php**

```
<!--Menu-->
<div class="rh_menu"> 
  <a href="#rhp_front_rhp_id" class="is-active" id="rhp_id">Front</a>    
  <a href="#rhp_front_ca_other_id" id="ca_other_id">Other</a>   
</div>
<!--Content Div-->
<div class="rhp_hide">
    <div class="rrp_container is-active" id="rhp_front_rhp_id">
        <div class="spinner is-active"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rrp_container" style="display:none;" id="rhp_front_ca_other_id">
        <div class="spinner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**01_house_rhp_id.php** <-- First button which is called by the Ajax

```
<div class="my_shortcode">
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[some_shortcode]'); ?>
</div>
```

**Function.php**

```
// load the javascript
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', '/03.includes/js/rh_ajax.js', array('jquery') );   
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

//Ajax call for House front page
function my_tab_callback() {  
    $template_part_path = 'page-parts/01_house_' . $_GET['id'];
    get_template_part($template_part_path);
    exit;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_my_tab', 'my_tab_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_tab', 'my_tab_callback');
```

**rh_ajax.js**

```
//To hide other divs
jQuery('.rh_menu a').click(function() {
    var rh_id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    jQuery('[id^="rhp_front_"]').hide();
    jQuery('#rhp_front_' + rh_id).show();
    });
//To initiate first click
jQuery(window).load(function() { 
    jQuery("#rhp_id" ).trigger( 'click' );  
    return false;       
    });
//Ajax call     
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.rh_menu a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var tab_house_id = jQuery(this).attr('id'); 


        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
            dataType: 'html',
            data: ({ action: 'my_tab', id: tab_house_id}),
            success: function(data){
                  jQuery('#rhp_front_' + tab_house_id).html(data);
                  console.log(data);

        },
        error: function(data)  
        {  
        alert("Nope");
        console.log(data);
        return false;
        }  

        }); 

   }); 
 });
```

So, it looks like when a shortcode is parsed by ajax, it is not recognized and gave me 500 server error.

How can I modify above setting so that I can use the shortcode within ajax setting?

Thanks!

Comment: url: ajax_object.ajax_url? What is the url exactly?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply. I tried a solution by "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27001518/using-a-do-shortcode-in-wordpress-via-an-ajax-call", but didn't work. And I got "ajax_object.ajax_url" from it.

Comment: Re-read [step 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27004631/383847). You need to use `wp_localize_script()` to define `ajax_object.ajax_url`. I always prefer using `wp_enqueue_script()` + `wp_localize_script()` versus adding scripts directly in the template.

Comment: Hi. I reedited the question above. I implemented your solution but I am still getting an error. I am still getting 500 (Internal Server Error). What am I doing wrong?  Thanks. I also changed shortcode to just simple paragraph to see if it works (to eliminate the possible shortcode error) . But I am got the same error.

Comment: Instead of `get_template_part` try using `ob_get_content`